# fonts render differently on GoogleFonts than on my page

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

I include say "Noto Sans" or "Ubuntu" on my webpage via css "@import".
If I compare the rendering on my page with the rendering on the GoogleFonts page it looks different for both fonts.
Even though I paste the same text into GoogleFonts and choose the same size, same background, same color.

Here is a picture: (especially visible with the "A")
[image]

Any idea if there is a setting I miss?
As you can see neither the weight nor the size matches. Especially the weight seems to be a problem. Comparing "Noto Sans" the font with the same weight looks much thicker on my page.
I downloaded the fonts from google into my system. But this also applies if I delete these fonts and the browser uses remote fonts.
I use MacOSX but checking in Browserstack it seems that the problem is effective in several browsers. I tested in Win7 with IE9 too.

Comment: Not sure about the IE browsers, but have you tried adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`? Google also uses `-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;` for IE.

Comment: yeah that's it, unfortunately I didn't saw that in the debug console.
could you paste it as an answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the IE browsers, but have you tried adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`? Google also uses `-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;` for IE.